# Send password in email notification WP

Tags: wordpress, passwords

Is there any way to send user password in function wp_new_user_notification, 
as I can see password is crypted using PasswordHash.

The problem is that i want to create user and then send him email notification with username and password and link so He can login without that two mail boring notification process.

If there is a plugin or someone find solution? I try few things butn nothing works, so if there is no cure i will leave it to be 2 steps.

Thanks

Comment: you might want to try adding it as part of the url however, you may need to check or validate part of that query string in your login page. you may try looking at [this page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/include-password-in-url).

Comment: Don't do that. It's a major security hole. Always hash user passwords.